# Can you use elements of fan inverted V for guying?

Tags: inverted-vee

Diagrams of fan inverted V antennas usually show the elements quite close together and parallel.
Anyone experience of, or insights about, spacing elements at say 90° or 120° around the tower to guy it? Would plan to keep the two elements of each dipole in the same plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable — and maybe even preferable, since it reduces the interaction between elements, making it easier to tune one band without messing up the others — as long as you don't care about the directionality being different on different bands, and the more complicated feedpoint arrangement.

XQ6FOD describes such a build [here](https://ludens.cl/Radiacti/antena/antena.html) (in Spanish, but machine translation does a decent job on it). You could make it smaller by omitting the 80m element, but be aware that the 80m element in this design also provides the resonances on the 17m and 12m bands (5th and 7th harmonics respectively).

Comment: I agree, it is absolutely preferable! Especially since the usual diagram of a fan dipole looking like some kind of stringed instrument doesn't allow for impedance adjustments by changing the angles between element pairs, and since you are operating a multi-band antenna at one height, you want to be able to tune the antenna, not just with element length, but also the angles between element pairs. (Angles between adjacent band pairs of other elements will also have a minor affect, but minimal compared to changing the angle of a specific pair of elements.) And, use a 1:1 BalUn !